# Describe the kernel and the range, and any vector such that T(p)=y.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{P_2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ be a linear transformation given by

$T(p)=[ p(0) ; p'(0)]$

Describe the kernel and range. That is to say, for what polynomials of the form

$p(t)= at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d$ does T map to zero?

Also, for what vectors of the form $y$ does $T(p) = y$ (The question also asked something
about $\mathbb{R^2}$  here but I just left the test and cannot remember completely. Any explanation is graciously accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made one error in your post. If $p\in\Bbb P_2,$ then $p(t)=at^2+bt+c$ for some constants $a,b,c$.

Now, $p'(t)=2at+b.$ Consequently, $p(0)=c$ and $p'(0)=b.$ What do we need to know about $b$ and $c,$ then, to know that $p$ is in the kernel of $T$?  How, then, can you describe the kernel of $T$?

Also, noting that $$T(p)=\begin{bmatrix}c\\b\end{bmatrix},$$ and that $b,c$ can be any real constants we like, what can you say about the range of $T$?

As for the last question, my suspicion is that it says something like: "Given $y\in\Bbb R^2,$ find some $p\in\Bbb P_2$ such that $T(p)=y,$ if possible." (That's what it would say, if I wrote the exam.) Once you've worked your way through my hint about the range, you should be able to answer this question readily.

Comment: My error was $\mathbb{P_3}$, but your answer just showed me how to do these problems so it's easy now; thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome.